# Qt slot callback breaks straight into my destructor

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Take a look at this amazing call stack:

```
1  FNFolderTreeDir::refreshSubDir                fnfoldertreedir.cpp               42   0x13faa3287   
2  FNFolderTreeDriveRootHive::processDirLoaded   fnfoldertreedriveroothive.cpp     25   0x13faa2175   
3  FNFolderTreeDriveRootHive::qt_static_metacall moc_fnfoldertreedriveroothive.cpp 74   0x13faa5df5   
4  QMetaObject::activate                         qobject.cpp                       3742 0x51744922
```

... lots of Qt internals here ...

```
33 _purecall                                     purevirt.c                        58   0x7feedc2d0cc 
34 FNFolderTreeNode::purge                       fnfoldertreenode.cpp              28   0x13fa9cf53   
35 FNFolderTreeNode::~FNFolderTreeNode           fnfoldertreenode.cpp              23   0x13fa9ceeb
```

`FNFolderTreeDriveRootHive::processDirLoaded` is a slot connected to the `QFileSystemModel::directoryLoaded` signal. So, what happened here is that my destructor was happily doing some internal cleanup when Qt interrupted it at a seemingly random point to call a slot to refresh the very object that has been reduced to the base class already. Of course, it crashed.

A couple of questions, if I may:

1. How is this even possible? I suspect that Qt used either `QAbstractItemModel::beginRemoveColumns` or `endRemoveRows` to dispatch the callback - I call them both in `FNFolderTreeNode::purge`. Should it not be doing this in main loop only?
2. How can I prevent this behaviour? Could try disconnecting the slot first thing in the destructor, but where is the guarantee that it will not be interrupted too?

Comment: Well, how exactly are the signal and slot connected ? Sounds more like a threading issue. May consider one of the other connection types: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum

Comment: "... lots of Qt internals here ..." - which are possibly the interesting parts

Comment: Try using the `deleteLater()`method to destroy the object. It makes sure your object is not destroy during the current event loop.

Comment: Also for deleteLater() or also disconnecting the object before deleting